# Does excel have a csv lint function?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does Excel have a csv lint function that will check to see if your file adheres to [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)?

Or does Microsoft just not include functionality like this on purpose?

Comment: You can write your own validation program using VBA, or some other language, but there are no real standards for CSV files.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld If that’s true why is there an RFC?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld And an online validator based on it?

Comment: From the RFC *" This memo provides information for the Internet community.  It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind"*

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It worked for the data I was trying to import.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It’s better than nothing.

Comment: That's a good thing.  But the RFC itself indicates it is not a standard.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld And by nothing, I mean excel.

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to use Excel.  But I think this discussion has strayed from the purpose of this group, so I will bow out.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Your Employer might.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this question is still relevant, but the [CSV Lint plug-in](https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/) for Notepad++ can check csv files for formating errors, missing quotes, datatypes, correct decimal character etc. Maybe not strictly(?) RFC4180 but it's something. It also adds syntax highlighting for both csv and fixed width data files, meaning each column gets a different color so it's easier to see.

[image: CSV Lint syntax highlighting columns]